# How to convert this Java code in C# code?

Tags: java, c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I tried to convert my Java code in C# but I missed something.

Java code

```
  public Map<String, MyDataClass> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setDataCarriers(Map<String, MyDataClass> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
```

Which is converted by tool like following:

```
public virtual IDictionary<string, MyDataClass> Data
        {
            get
            {
                return data;
            }
            set
            {
                this.data = value;
            }
        }
```

but getting error:

> Using the generic type 'MyDataClass' requires 1 type arguments

Java code

```
public class MyDataClass<T> implements Serializable {

    private T demohere;

    public T get() {
        return demohere;
    }

    public void set(T demohere) {
        this.demohere= demohere;
    }
 }
```

Converted to C#

```
 [Serializable]
    public class MyDataClass<T>
    {
        private T demohere;
        
        public virtual T demohere
        {
            get
            {
                return demohere;
            }
            set
            {
                this.demohere= value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change type of `Data` to `IDictionary<String, MyDataClass>` and remove type argument `<T>` from `MyDataClass`

Comment: @Neo remove type argument `<T>` from `MyDataClass` definition. As I can see, in your Java code this class is not generic.

Comment: @Neo please next times add full code snippets related to the question.

Comment: @Neo so now I can say, that you should now insert back type argument with type you want to use, like `<string>` or `<object>` or whatever you need.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Neo take a look later https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: i did it like this ` public virtual IDictionary<string, MyDataClass<string>> MyDataClass`